# isotope filter image strange animate and shaking few second when i click on the filter menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-isotope

When i click on the filter menu, then the container image animated but problem is this image shake few second when the animation end. [here is this demo``](http://192.185.184.65/~neterp/it1/Bino/)

my code is here

```js
// JavaScript

jQuery(document).ready(function($){
 // Activate isotope in container
 $(".portfolio_active").isotope({
  itemSelector: '.single_item',
  layoutMode: 'fitRows',
 });
 
 $(".portfolio_active").isotope({
  filter: '*',
 });
    
 // Add isotope click function
    
 $('.portfolio_nav li').click(function(){
  $(".portfolio_nav li").removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass("active");
            var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
            $(".portfolio_active").isotope({
                filter: selector,
                animationOptions: {
                    duration:750,
                    easing: 'linear',
                    queue: false,
            }
  });
            return false;
     });
});
```

```css
/* CSS */

.portfolio_section {
 padding: 100px 0;
 background: #ffffff;
}
.portfolio_nav {
 margin-top: 50px;
}
.portfolio_nav li {
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 color: #999999;
 cursor: pointer;
 display: inline;
 font-size: 14px;
 margin-right: 20px;
 padding-right: 20px;
 position: relative;
}
.portfolio_nav li.active {
 color: #e74c3c;
}
.portfolio_nav li::before {
 background: #999999 none repeat scroll 0 0;
 content: "";
 height: 60%;
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
 top: 25%;
 transform: rotate(20deg);
 width: 2px;
}
.portfolio_nav li:last-child::before {
 display: none;
}
.portfolio_active {
 margin-top: 45px;
}
.single_item {
 width: 25%;
 float: left;
 position: relative;
 transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->

<section class="portfolio_section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
        <h2 class="section_title">RECENT WORKS</h2>
        <p class="para_title">It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap scrambled it to make a type.</p>
        <div class="title_icon"><span class="fa fa-circle"></span></div>
      </div>
      <!-- end col-xs-12 -->
      <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
        <div class="portfolio_nav">
          <ul>
            <li class="active" data-filter="*">ALL</li>
            <li data-filter=".print">PRINT DESIGN</li>
            <li data-filter=".animation">ANIMATION</li>
            <li data-filter=".art">ART</li>
            <li data-filter=".webdesign">WEB DESIGN</li>
            <li data-filter=".photography">PHOTOGRAPHY</li>
            <li data-filter=".video">VIDEO</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="portfolio_active">
    <div class="single_item print animation"><img src="images/portfolio/2.jpg" alt="1.jpg">
      <div class="hover_caption">
        <h4>T-SHIRT DESIGN</h4>
        <span><a href="">art</a> / <a href="">t-shirt</a></span> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="single_item animation art print"><img src="images/portfolio/3.jpg" alt="1.jpg"></div>
    <div class="single_item art webdesign"><img src="images/portfolio/4.jpg" alt="1.jpg"></div>
    <div class="single_item webdesign"><img src="images/portfolio/5.jpg" alt="1.jpg"></div>
    <div class="single_item photography"><img src="images/portfolio/6.jpg" alt="1.jpg"></div>
    <div class="single_item print webdesign"><img src="images/portfolio/7.jpg" alt="1.jpg"></div>
    <div class="single_item video webdesign"><img src="images/portfolio/8.jpg" alt="1.jpg"></div>
    <div class="single_item webdesign"><img src="images/portfolio/1.jpg" alt="1.jpg"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 3):

It is related to this css in your styles.css file (it's actually in there twice).

```
.single_item{
width:25%;
float: left;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
transition:0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

remove the following statement from each:

```
transition:0.5s ease-in-out;
```

Comment: If it answers your question, please mark it answered. Thanks!

Comment: Please accept my answer if it fixed your issue. [accepting answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)